# Azure DevOps yaml not picking up the parameters

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops

```
parameters:     
- name: environment    
  displayName: Environment to choose    
  type: string    

variables:    
  azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
  functionAppName: 'samplemahesh'
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'
  workingDirectory: '$(system.default)'

stages:
- stage: DevBuildStage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'DEV'))
  displayName: Dev_Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: command1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "npm run ${{ parameters.environment }}"


- stage: QaBuildStage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'QAM'))
  displayName: QA_Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: command1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "npm run ${{ parameters.environment }}"


- stage: ProdBuildStage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'PRD'))
  displayName: Prod_Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: command1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "npm run ${{ parameters.environment }}"




- stage: DeploytoDev
  displayName: Deploy to Dev 
  dependsOn: DevBuildStage
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'dev'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                
                Write-Host "Deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}"


- stage: DeploytoQA
  displayName: Deploy to QA
  dependsOn: QaBuildStage
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'qa'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                
                Write-Host "Deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}"



- stage: DeploytoProd
  displayName: Deploy to Prod
  dependsOn: ProdBuildStage
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'prod'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                
                Write-Host "Deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}"
```

This code is working fine initially , now only for DEV parameter it is working , for other parameters it is not working ... Please help on this .... I want to use single yaml file to deploy the code on all the three environments with condition option

Answer (score 0):

The structure is not correct on your side.

[image]

The Below will work:

```
trigger:
- none

parameters:     
- name: environment    
  displayName: Environment to choose    
  type: string
  values:
    - DEV
    - QAM
    - PRD

variables:    
  azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
  functionAppName: 'samplemahesh'
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'
  workingDirectory: '$(system.default)'

stages:
- stage: DevBuildStage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'DEV'))
  dependsOn: []
  displayName: Dev_Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: command1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "npm run ${{ parameters.environment }}"


- stage: QaBuildStage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'QAM'))
  dependsOn: []
  displayName: QA_Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: command1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "npm run ${{ parameters.environment }}"


- stage: ProdBuildStage
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'PRD'))
  dependsOn: []
  displayName: Prod_Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build_Job
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: command1
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "npm run ${{ parameters.environment }}"




- stage: DeploytoDev
  displayName: Deploy to Dev 
  dependsOn: DevBuildStage
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'dev'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                
                Write-Host "Deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}"


- stage: DeploytoQA
  displayName: Deploy to QA
  dependsOn: QaBuildStage
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'qa'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                
                Write-Host "Deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}"



- stage: DeploytoProd
  displayName: Deploy to Prod
  dependsOn: ProdBuildStage
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'prod'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                
                Write-Host "Deploy to ${{ parameters.environment }}"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much .. I got struck with this issue from the past 4 hours...... I want to use this for my angular application and have three different builds per environments ... Suggest still any changes needed

Comment: @MaheshReddy Hi Mahesh, do you have more confusion? If no, can we [end this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIbVc.png)? This will help others who have the similar issue. Best Regards.

Comment: I don't have any confusion ..just asking you in case of if I want to perform rollback any suggestions ?

Comment: @MaheshReddy Could you please clarify about 'perform rollback any suggestions', is this another question?

Comment: ..Yes its another question